# How to write query in ORACLE and SQL_SERVER to get records with the most statuses?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

for the table below

```
tenant_id | status_id
----------------------
   3      |   6
---------------------
   5      |   7
---------------------
   7      |   7
--------------------
   3      |   7
-------------------
   3      |   7
--------------------
   5      |   7
```

we can see that:

- tenant_id=3 has 1 record with status_id=6
- tenant_id=5 has 2 record with status_id=7
- tenant_id=7 has 1 record with status_id=7
- tenant_id=3 has 2 record with status_id=7

For given STATUS_ID_PARAM I want to get all tenants that has the most records with that `STATUS_ID_PARAM`.
For the example above, for `STATUS_ID_PARAM = 7`, the query should return 2 records:

```
   tenant_id | status_id
   --------------------
      3      |   7
   --------------------
      5      |   7
```

because those tenants has the most records(2 for each one) with status_id=7.

I tried something like this,  but I don't know how to continue or may be there is another way:

```
select tenant_id, count(status_id) s
from candidate
where status_id = STATUS_ID_PARAM 
group by tenant_id, status_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work in both Oracle and SQL Server

```
select tenant_id, s
from
  (       
    select tenant_id,
           count(*) as s,
           rank() over(order by count(*) desc) as rn
    from candidate
    where status_id = 7
    group by tenant_id
  ) T
where rn = 1;
```

(Tested on SQL Server 2005->2012 and Oracle 11g R2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select tenant_id, count(status_id) s
from candidate
where status_id = STATUS_ID_PARAM 
group by tenant_id, status_id
having count(status_id) = (select max(count(status_id)) from candidate)
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get error `group function is nested too deeply`

Comment: try it now... i have changed the answer

Comment: this will not work
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select tenant_id, count(status_id) s
from candidate
where status_id = STATUS_ID_PARAM 
AND count(status_id) = MAX(count(status_id))
group by tenant_id, status_id
```

Comment: this will not work, you can't use aggrigate functions in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

I Edited the answer :)

```
select tenant_id, count(status_id) s
from candidate can
where status_id = 7
group by tenant_id, status_id
having COUNT(status_id) 
in 
(
select top 1 count(status_id) from candidate 
group by status_id,tenant_id
order by COUNT(status_id) desc
)
```

Comment: how to cancel my edit? i edited someone else's answer by mistake :(

Comment: @Vikram - You can click on the link after the text "edited" and the select "rollback".